# How to undo an alias in Mac

Tags: macos, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard

I mistakenly have made an alias of my Drive in the desktop, and just trying to figure out how to undo the alias? When I drop that alias into the trash, it gives me a warning, that everything will be deleted, and I am scared that I don't want to trash my entire drive. Is there anyway in terminal to un-alias the content?

Thanks

Comment: This question belongs on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that you can unalias the drive, but I wouldn't think deleting the alias would delete your data.  It's basically just a newer version of the 'ln -s' symlink from Unix / linux systems.

Just make sure you are only trashing the alias.  Have you CTRL+clicked (right clicked) the alias to see what your options are?

If nothing else, make a backup, disconnect / unmount the backup partition or drive, then trash the alias.

Comment: yes you were right, that popup is being brought up everytime. I was worried that I might end up losing the data. Not sure if you even "Trash" your drive like that.. just a thought though.. haha. Now this gives me another prospective of really back up my data.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem moving the alias to the thash and then emptying the trash. I just did this, and my hard disk is still OK.

If you want to remove the alias in Terminal, enter:

```
rm ~/Desktop/Macintosh\ HD\ alias
```

Or substitute the name of your alias.

Comment: Moving the alias to the trash moved everything to the trash. However the `rm`works fine.